# Is it possible to output a data stream to a PDF using ABCpdf?

Tags: c#, .net, database, charts, pdf-generation

I would like to use abcPDF (.net) generator to output a stream of data from a DB into a PDF file that can then be output as a file via button. I know that abcPDF can be used to output a file independently, but I would like to generate data from a survey, populate a DB, and then later on, the user can generate a PDF that has data charts that can be streamed into the pdf as bits from an image made by .netCharting.

Any possible solutions using these two?

Thanks!

Comment: I would ping the authors of that licensed library regarding questions on it.

Comment: plenty of people have used ABCpdf for situations like above, so I don't want to exhaust these options. Thanks for the advice though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for doc.AddImageData() which will allow you to pass the data from the db to create a pdf file.